# manually triggering didSelectRowAtIndexPath in cellForRowAt results in a nil cell in actual didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm trying to manually call the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`in cell creation `cellForRowAt`, because that will update the detail view without having to physically touch the row, but when I do so I get a nil error on cell definition inside the actual delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, while if I don call it inside `cellForRowAt` it works as expected. I'm assuming that at cell creation time there is actually no cells to read hence the nil value. 
How can than perform the logic inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` at cell creation time? I thought of opening curly brackets and put the logic there would work but it doesn't accept brackets there.

Can you see if I'm implementing the call to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` correctly? Many thanks as always.
This are the functions:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookingCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTableViewCell
        let booking = self.fetchedResultController?.object(at: indexPath)
        // Configure the cell...

        cell.cellId = booking!.bookingId

        cell.bookingId = booking!.bookingId
        print(booking!.bookingId)
        cell.bookingIdInfoLabel.text = booking!.bookingId

        cell.bookingDate = booking!.bookingDate
        cell.bookingDateInfoLabel.text = booking?.bookingDate

        cell.bookingStart = booking!.bookingStart
        cell.bookingStartInfoLabel.text = booking?.bookingStart

        cell.bookingEnd = booking!.bookingEnd
        cell.bookingEndInfoLabel.text = booking?.bookingEnd

        cell.bookingPrice = booking!.bookingPrice
        cell.worksDescription = booking!.worksList

        cell.customerName = booking!.customerName
        cell.customerNameInfoLabel.text = booking?.customerName

        cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        cell.cellView.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.bookingIdInfoLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        cell.bookingIdInfoLabel.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.bookingDateInfoLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        cell.bookingDateInfoLabel.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.bookingStartInfoLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        cell.bookingStartInfoLabel.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.bookingEndInfoLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        cell.bookingEndInfoLabel.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.customerNameInfoLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        cell.customerNameInfoLabel.clipsToBounds = true

        // set the corresponding row for the selected time slot's booking as selected
        if cell.cellId == self.bookingId {
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle) // select timeslot's corresponding row
            self.tableView(self.bookingTableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

        }
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! BookingTableViewCell

        print("selected cell id is : \(cell.cellId!)")
        self.bookingIdInfoLabel.text = cell.bookingId
        self.bookingDateInfoLabel.text = cell.bookingDate
        self.bookingStartInfoLabel.text = cell.bookingStart
        self.bookingEndInfoLabel.text = cell.bookingEnd
        self.priceInfoLabel.text = cell.bookingPrice
        self.customerInfoLabel.text = cell.customerName
        self.worksDescriptionInfoTextVIew.text = cell.worksDescription

    }
```

Comment: All the things you perform inside didSelectRow seem to be related to your ViewController. So why don't you set the data inside cellForRow itself, instead of calling didSelectRow. I would recommend not to call call delegate methods from outside. Instead move your implementation outside in a different function, and call that function from both didSelect and cellForRow methods

Comment: **Never, never, never** call delegate methods containing `did`, `will` and `should` yourself. Those methods are called exclusively by the framework.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma I need to be able to select another row and display details for the newly selected row, that's why I set the logic inside `didSelect`. What I'm basically trying to achieve is that I get automatically selected cell when first load but then be able to select any other row.

Comment: You can always use setSelected property of the cell to show it as selected. Never try to manually select cell and call tableview delegate or datasource methods yourself. Try separating your code in smaller methods and use those methods to manipulate data and available properties of tableview to update your UI

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma in what `setSelected`is different from `.selectRow`? I see that `.selectRow` just sets the background to the `selected` state color right?

Comment: They seem to be same. So for the UI you can call any of them. But calling didSelect row is not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new function where you change text of labels depending the booking selection

```
func updateSelection(_ selectedBooking: Booking) {
    print("selected cell id is : \(booking.bookingId!)")
    self.bookingIdInfoLabel.text = booking.bookingId
    self.bookingDateInfoLabel.text = booking.bookingDate
    self.bookingStartInfoLabel.text = booking.bookingStart
    self.bookingEndInfoLabel.text = booking.bookingEnd
    self.priceInfoLabel.text = booking.bookingPrice
    self.customerInfoLabel.text = booking.customerName
    self.worksDescriptionInfoTextVIew.text = booking.worksList
}
```

In `didSelectRowAt` call this method like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.updateSelection(self.fetchedResultController?.object(at: indexPath))
}
```

call the same method in `cellForRowAt`

```
if booking!.bookingId == self.bookingId {
    self.updateSelection(self.fetchedResultController?.object(at: indexPath))
}
    return cell
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly thanks. But how it this different from what I was doing before? Is that lag time in calling another function enough to actually have `cellForRowAt` finished running? I actually had the idea of going for this approach but thought that it would be the same -> nil ..

Comment: @vincenzo The crucial difference is that the labels are updated from the **model** rather than from the **view**. Unlike cells the data source array is always available. Basically you are discouraged from misusing the cell as data model anyway.

Comment: When `cell.cellId == self.bookingId` you called didSelectRowAt even before the cellForRow returns the created cell. So it will be nil

Comment: @vadian I thought using defer in cellForRow if cell.cellId == self.bookingId. But in defer cell is nil. Do you know why?

Comment: Same situation: **Don't** get data from the cell, write  `if booking!.cellId == self.bookingId`

Comment: @vadian I see.. I was definitely misusing `cell`..thanks for explaining it.

Comment: @vincenzo And please declare the fetched results controller as (lazy) non-optional to avoid all that ugly force unwrapping and optional chaining.

Comment: @vadian  I don't understand the `if booking!.cellId == self.bookingId`difference. I perform a check to see if the `cell`i'm about to create has the same id as the `bookingId`and do some UI changes..

and yes I have to change `fetchResultController`as lazy non-optional..thos force unwraps are awful..

Comment: Sorry I mean `if booking!.bookingId == self.bookingId`. As I said it's very bad practice to get data from the cell. Actually you are going to check if the current **data source item** has the same `bookingId`

Comment: @vadian I see your point, this way I don't use cell's properties, but I get the parameter to check directly from fetched results..

Comment: I asked a new question because I have similar problem in the step before this one in my app but I can't really apply this solution I guess, and I would appreciate if you guys could give it a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638110/trying-to-update-a-collection-view-when-tableview-cell-matches-a-criteria-swift

Comment: @vadian could you please check my new question?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR could you also please check my new question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would suggest

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookingCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTableViewCell
    let booking = self.fetchedResultController?.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.config(booking:booking)
    if booking.bookingId == self.bookingId {
        self.performChanges(forBooking:booking)
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! BookingTableViewCell
    let booking = cell.booking
    self.performChanges(forBooking:booking)
}

func performChanges(booking:Booking) {
    //perform all the changes that you did in didSelectRow before
}

//Inside cell
var booking:Booking?
func config(booking:Booking) {
    self.booking = booking
    //set all the data and manipulate the ui here
}
```

Did not test this code, but hope you get the gist. If you need more info or not able to understand what exactly is to be done, drop a comment and I can elaborate more.